# Cómo obtener un botón en cypress que cambia de nombre

Tags: cypress

Actualmente estoy automatizando un módulo en el que tengo que hacer clic en un botón que puedo identificarme con la herramienta cypress y me dice que llame a por para decir algo *button1*, entonces coloco mi `cy.get('button1').click()`, sin embargo al ejecutarlo no encuentra el elemento y cuando reviso el button ahora se llama *button2*, y así sucesivamente. ¿Cómo podría hacer en ese caso? esto es parte del codigo que tengo

```js
cy.get('#btn_bo_prorrogas_ver1 > .fa').click();
```

He intentado tal vez hacerlo con una variable pero sin éxito:

```js
const buttonName = Cypress.config('current_button_name'); cy.get(#${buttonName}).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

en cypres V 11.2 hay un botón parecido al de un franco tirador que al seleccionarlo te permite  seleccionar el elemento que deseas editar y te brinda el codigo para colocarlo en el archivo .cy

[image: Cypress v 11.2]

[image: Cypress Boton seleccionado]

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que tienes un botón de esta forma:

```
<button
  id="btn_bo_prorrogas_ver1"
  class="btn"
  name="submission"
  role="button"
  data-cy="submit"
>
  Submit
</button>
```

Donde intentas acceder usando la expresión `"#btn_bo_prorrogas_ver1 > .fa"` que contiene el **id** pero lo recomendable es que contenga un atributo definido `data-cy` que en este caso contiene `"submit"` entonces podrías acceder a este usando `cy.get('[data-cy="submit"]').click()`, no creo que sea necesario modificar la configuración por defecto para la tarea que propones.

Otra manera adicional para buscar un boton:

```
<div class="local">
  <button class="my-button">Click me</button>
</div>

cy.get('.local').shadow().find('.my-button').click()
```